# log4j 2 configuration: appenderRef.xyz.ref?

Tags: java, log4j

From https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html:

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile

   ...

logger.rolling.name = org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling
logger.rolling.level = debug
logger.rolling.additivity = false
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

What does the last line do? I get that `logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling` causes the `rolling` logger to point towards the `rolling` appender, but  I don't understand the last line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling
```

first declares a set of appender references by name. Here, it declares one named `rolling`. This `rolling` is unrelated to the `rolling` in

```
appenders = console, rolling, list
```

This

```
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

uses the previously declared name to refer to the appender reference. The `.ref` then connects that appender reference with the appender named `RollingFile`.

Comment: oh -- ok, so the pair of lines effectively does something like `appenderRefs['rolling'] = RollingFile`

Comment: @JasonS That's my understanding. But I could not extract specific quotes from the documentation or the plugin source code.